# command to install 32bit packages (lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0) on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Tags: software-installation

I would like to install 32bit libraries to run dynamically linked code on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS operating system.

Tried two commands, none of them work:

*Command no. 1:*

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lib32bz2-1.0 : PreDepends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.9-18) but it is not going to be installed
 lib32ncurses5 : Depends: lib32tinfo5 (= 5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 lib32z1 : Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

*Command no. 2:*

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0

E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate
```

What is the appropriate command to install 32bit libraries?

Looking through other posts people tell execute the shell commands above to fix the error, but for me the *commands* do not work.

*I've also executed*

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

since other posts recommended to execute it. It does not seem to help either. When trying to run a file:

```
./vsim
```

I get the error

```
bash: ./vsim: No such file or directory
```

although the file "vsim" exists:

```
vsim: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.4, BuildID[sha1]=31fa816092d910bb32b64ed8ea2a5baa1da6b005, stripped
```

Comment: thx for formatting, sorry that didn't put code in separate blocks

Answer (score 1):

According to this article from Humble Bundle: https://support.humblebundle.com/hc/en-us/articles/202759400-Installing-32-bit-libs-on-a-64-bit-Linux-system

As of Ubuntu 13.04, **ia32-libs** was replaced by **lib32z1**, which in turn depends on **libc6-i386**. Try the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32z1
```

You may or may not need lib32ncurses5 or lib32bz2-1.0.

- If you do need lib32bz2-1.0, it should install fine once you have installed libc6-i386 (using the command above).
- If you do need lib32ncurses5, you will also need to install lib32tinfo5

You can install lib32tinfo5 as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32tinfo5
```

If you need 32-bit versions of additional libraries for which both 32- and 64-bit versions exist, you can use the suffix **:i386** to explicitly install the 32-bit version of the package. For example:

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2-plugins:i386
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32z1` gives message: `libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.5 is to be installed` but terminal says that `libc6 is already the newest version`

Comment: it seems that the shell messes up with what I've already installed and what not. Is there an easy way to remove ALL 32bit packages and then reinstall from scratch?